# Kendo Grid get row and column index on Change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have the following code:

```
function grd_onChange(e) {
    var grid = $("#grd").data("kendoGrid");

    var selectedCell = grid.select();
    var index = selectedCell.index();
    var row = selectedCell.closest("tr");
    var col = selectedCell.closest("td");
    alert(row);
}
```

I would like to know how can I get the column index when a user clicks on a cell of a particular row of the grid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<body>
    <script>

        function onChange(arg) {
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var row = this.select().closest("tr");
            var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
            var colIdx = this.select().index();
            alert(rowIdx + '-' + colIdx);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                Freight: { type: "number" },
                                ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },

                selectable: "multiple cell",
                change: onChange,
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "OrderID",
                    filterable: false
                },
                                "Freight",
                                {
                                    field: "OrderDate",
                                    title: "Order Date",
                                    width: 120,
                                    format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                                }, {
                                    field: "ShipName",
                                    title: "Ship Name",
                                    width: 260
                                }, {
                                    field: "ShipCity",
                                    title: "Ship City",
                                    width: 150
                                }
                ]
            });
        });

    </script>
    <div id="Grid"></div>
</body>
```

OR

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    $(grid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var rowIdx = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);
        var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);
        alert(rowIdx + '-' + colIdx);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        OrderID: { type: "number" },
                        Freight: { type: "number" },
                        ShipName: { type: "string" },
                        OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                        ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        dataBound: onDataBound,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "OrderID",
            filterable: false
        },
                        "Freight",
                        {
                            field: "OrderDate",
                            title: "Order Date",
                            width: 120,
                            format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                        }, {
                            field: "ShipName",
                            title: "Ship Name",
                            width: 260
                        }, {
                            field: "ShipCity",
                            title: "Ship City",
                            width: 150
                        }
                    ]
    });
});


<div id="Grid"></div>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  But it does not work yet.  If I click on a cell of a row, it either displays 0-0, 1-1, or 2-2.  Maybe is it due to my first 3 columns are template column containing a check box?

Comment: I understand why it did not work on my side.  You have set to cell selection rather than row selection.  How do you make it work for row selection?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to get cell index on row section instead of cell section. I have also added another method which was help you to get the cell and row index on click.

Comment: Databound example is working properly, but onChange is always displaying 0-0,1-1 as in ist comment